# Let $E/F$ a field extension. If $x\in E$ is separable over $F$ is $E/F$ separable?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $E/F$ a field extension. If $x\in E$ is separable over $F$ is $E/F$ separable ?

I would say yes since the fact that $x$ separable over $F$ implies $E(x)/F$ separable, an since $E=E(x)$ then $E/F$ would be separable. But I'm not sure if this argument is valid.

Comment: It actually just implies that $F(x)/F$ is separable. Otherwise every field extension would be separable (just take an element $x \in F$ which is always separable over $F$).

Comment: An extension may contain elements that are separable over the base and also elements that are inseparable.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the assumption $E=F(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is more or less contained in the comments by Lubin and Menag. I simply give a specific example of a situation they described.

Let $F=\Bbb{F}_p(x)$ be the field of rational functions with coefficients in $\Bbb{F}_p$. Of course, $p$ is a prime number. For convenience I assume that $p>3$. Let then $y$ be a solution of $y^2=x^3+1$. Then the minimal polynomial of $y$ is $T^2-(x^3+1)\in F[T]$. Its zeros are $\pm y$. These are distinct, so $y$ is separable. It follows that the extension $F[y]/F$ is separable.

But if you do not assume that $E=F[y]$, then we have the following possibility. We may have $E=F[y,z]$, where $z$ is a zero of $z^p=x$. Then $E/F$ will not be separable even though there are separable elements in $E$.

---

OTOH if you assume that $E=F[x]$ is an algebraic extension such that $x$ is separable over $F$, then the extension $E/F$ is separable itself. IOW all the elements of $E$ have separable minimal polynomials over $F$. This follows from the fact that separable elements of an algebraic extension form an intermediate field. See, for example, Section 8.7 in *Jacobson's Basic Algebra II* for the details.

---

An algebraic extension $E/F$ is called *purely inseparable* if no element from $E\setminus F$ has a separable minimal polynomial. When this happens all the elements $z\in E$ satisfy $z^{p^n}\in F$ for some positive integer $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $E=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/6})$, which is clearly not separable, since it's a real field and the minimal polynomial $x^6-2$ has non-real roots. However, $\sqrt{2}\in E$ and is separable, since all the roots of $x^2-2$ are in $E$. Thus the claim is false.

What's going on here is that the selected element isn't necessarily enough to generate the whole field; it might generate a subfield. If you add the hypothesis that $F(x)=E$, then it works.

Comment: Hmm. Surely $E/\Bbb{Q}$ is separable. Separability means that the minimal polynomials of elements of $E$ do not have zeros of multiplicities $>1$ in the splitting field of that polynomial. Those zeros do not need to belong to $E$. That condition is called normality. All finite extensions of fields of characteristic zero are separable.